# Unable to create role from GCP Editor role

Tags: google-cloud-platform, permissions, editor, roles, google-iam

I am trying to create a role from Editor role removing few permissions. I keep getting the error 'create role failed'. There are no details on the error.

I was able to create a custom role using 'Workflows Invoker' but not with Editor or Owner role. Is there any restriction on these roles?

Comment: In Google Cloud, there are usually four different methods to accomplish something (GUI, CLI, SDK, REST/gRPC). Edit your post a clearly show what you tried.